# RocksDB total memory usage

Tags: rocksdb

I'm looking at an example RocksDB option configuration:

```
opts = rocksdb.Options()
opts.create_if_missing = True
opts.max_open_files = 300000
opts.write_buffer_size = 67108864
opts.max_write_buffer_number = 3
opts.target_file_size_base = 67108864

opts.table_factory = rocksdb.BlockBasedTableFactory(
    filter_policy=rocksdb.BloomFilterPolicy(10),
    block_cache=rocksdb.LRUCache(2 * (1024 ** 3)),
    block_cache_compressed=rocksdb.LRUCache(500 * (1024 ** 2)))
```

https://python-rocksdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/

It says

> It assings a cache of 2.5G, uses a bloom filter for faster lookups and
> keeps more data (64 MB) in memory before writting a .sst file.

Does this mean it uses a maximum memory of 2.5GB or 64MB?

And why is the cache 2.5GB? `(2 * (1024 ** 3))` is 2 billion, not 2.5 billion?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean it uses a maximum memory of 2.5GB or 64MB?

NO. It means the block cache will cost 2.5GB, and the in-memory table will cost `64 * 3`MB, since there are 3 (`opts.max_write_buffer_number`) buffers, each is of size 64MB (`opts.write_buffer_size`). Besides that, Rocksdb still need some other memory for index and bloom filer blocks. Check [this](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Memory-usage-in-RocksDB) for detail.

> And why is the cache 2.5GB? (2 * (1024 ** 3)) is 2 billion, not 2.5 billion?

Because there're 2GB uncompressed block cache (`block_cache`), and 0.5GB compressed block cache (`block_cache_compressed`).

Comment: Is there a way I can optimise for memory, because I'm not doing any reads, I'm just doing writes?

Comment: If there's no read, you don't need config a bloom filter and LRU cache for your database. Also you can use less open files, and small write buffers to reduce usages of memory, however, that might cause performance penalty.

Comment: I read the best way to reduce memory is to increase `block_size` but this requires BlockTableOptions and i wasnt sure how to create NewLRUCache() for that? I think i can also set cache_index to true?